# xcode+deselect the cell in tableviewcontroller

Tags: xcode, tableview

I had taken `tableview` in `viewcontroller`. Now I had wrote a code to navigate to other controller when particular row is selected.

Example:-on selecting the 1st index user navigates ---> `Tableview` navigates to `mapview`

Now on clicking on back button on `mapview` user navigates ---> `mapview` to `Tableview`

Now the problem I am facing is when I navigate to `tableview` from `mapview` I can see the by default the 1st row selected.

And I want that when I navigates to `tableview` from `mapview` no row should be shown as selected.

What should I write and where so that no row by default is selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to be doing this in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
       [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
```